# Hyperloop and Google Mobile Ads SDK

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-hyperloop, hyperloop

I'm trying to use Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK in my appcelerator project since ti.admob (https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.admob) doesn't seem to support rewarded ads. So I created a Podfile in the top project directory:

```ruby
install! 'cocoapods',
         :integrate_targets => false

platform :ios, '7.0'

target 'my app' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '7.15'
end
```

(I couldn't use the latest version of the pod, Xcode bailed on some type declaration issue - this one compiled fine.)

Then I used the library, like this:

```js
var GADRequest = require('GoogleMobileAds/GADRequest');
var GADRewardBasedVideoAd = require('GoogleMobileAds/GADRewardBasedVideoAd');
var instance = GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance();
if (!instance.isReady()) {
  var request = new GADRequest();
  instance.loadRequest(request, Alloy.CFG.rewardedadid);
}
```

And the code failed with error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
(evaluating 'instance.loadRequest(request, Alloy.CFG.rewardedadid)')
```

Looking at the corresponding generated .js file at `./build/hyperloop/ios/js/googlemobileads/gadrewardbasedvideoad.js`, I noticed that function signatures for instance methods and properties are generated for all that is in `GADRewardBasedVideoAd.h` except for `loadRequest()`. The header entry for `loadRequest()` is:

```objc
- (void)loadRequest:(GADRequest *)request withAdUnitID:(NSString *)adUnitID;
```

The only noticeable difference with this is that it's using a named parameter. Is there anything special with this kind of method? Am I doing something wrong or does Hyperloop not yet support such functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you are not including the full signature (missing the `withAdUnitID:` selector). For fixing it, simply concatenate parameters in Hyperloop like this:

```js
// Compiles to native "loadRequest:withAdUnitID:"
instance.loadRequestWithAdUnitID(request, Alloy.CFG.rewardedadid);
```

This is documented in the [Named Methods](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/iOS+Hyperloop+Programming+Guide#iOSHyperloopProgrammingGuide-Namedmethods) section of the [Hyperloop Programming Guide](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/iOS+Hyperloop+Programming+Guide).

Tip: There is an [open source example](https://github.com/hyperloop-modules/titanium-admob) of using the Google Mobile Ads Android Library on Hyperloop as well, try it out!

Comment: Notice wasn't there back when I was wrestling with the (I'll be bold) non-working versions of Hyperloop.